# linux dlopen can i get notification in my library when dlopen() is called in a process?

Tags: linux, process, wrapper, dlopen

can i get the notification in my library in a process, whenever any new library is loaded from any other library in the same process with dlopen() function on linux? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Build a [library interposer](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/lib_interposers.html) that interposes `dlopen()`.

> With dynamic linking, you can intercept any function call an application makes to any shared library. Once you intercept it, you can do whatever you want in that function, as well as call the real function the application originally intended to call.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at rtld-audit - auditing API for the dynamic linker.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/rtld-audit.7.html

You should build a shared library with specific functions, and you should be notified with the different events. Once you have your library you will need to set LD_AUDIT to your shared library.